# Can I take the submit button out of the form builder somehow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using `form_for` to make a form. However, I want the submit button `<%= f.submit "Submit" %>` to be inside another element that's not inside the form. I can't just put the element inside the form -- it's separated by too much html. Is there a way to take this submit button out and put it in another `div` or just use plain html to submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

If Javascript is an option you could just make a button outside of the form and bind its onClick with something like

`document.getElementById("myForm").submit();`